# Can IsolatedStorage of Windows phone be hacked?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage

I use my app to download file then I save into IsolatedStorage. 
Can someone hack and get my files or folders from my app? 
I do not know how IsolatedStorage protects its data? Do we have another ways to protect data in IsolatedStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your data is vulnerable.

If this data contains user details, like emails, passwords or even personal information then this should be made secure.

If you are storing information about a user's favourite colour or favourite car then this CAN be deemed as "not sensitive" and you will then have to decide whether you want to protect this.

Always assume that people can get at your data. It's just a matter of time before they can access it (just look at how people have jailbroken the iPhone and a vast array of other smart phones for that matter).

Remember [Security is not obtained through Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)

Comment: You say yes, yet you supply no evidence to back it up.  Plus I don't know how obscurity applies to isolated storage... there's nothing obscure about it.

Answer (score 0):

The following link has good answers in relation to Isolated Storage on Windows...

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5660/how-secure-is-isolated-storage-on-windows

From within a managed application it's not going to be possible to access the Isolated Storage of another application.  However from native code that's another matter, and WP8 has support for native code...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681687(v=vs.105).aspx

Plus The following article asserts that there's only a registry in the way of a hacker who wants to get unmanaged code on to WP 7.1...

http://www.wpcentral.com/let-hacking-begin-how-windows-phone-7-can-run-native-unmanaged-code

So on WP7 it's pretty clear your app shouldn't store any sensitive data in isolated storage on WP and on WP8 it's even clearer.  If you can avoid putting sensitive data in isolated storage do so, otherwise you'll need to encrypt the data, and then of course you need to consider the security of the encryption and the keys used to decrypt and encrypt the data.  The following looks like a good guide on how to do that best...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh487164(v=vs.105).aspx

At the end of the day security is nothing more than a series of hurdles for a hacker, ultimately they'll probably get access to the data if they're really determined and have the skills and resources available to do so.